# wordpress - error URL while delete some file manager in cpanel

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I've deleted some unused file in file manager on cpanel,

but when I check my domain, it's take an effect of it, I dunno what happen, or maybe I've deleted wrong file that's needed to work with wordpress or something like that,

can someone help me how to fix it??

`Error`
    *Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.*

I've tried:

1. Update php version to 5.6 and downgrade to 5.4 but no effect,
2. check extentions php and sure mysql checked

Comment: Please see below url , Same question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694568/php-your-php-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-mysql-extension-which-is-r

Comment: @Ashkar i've read the link of that, but I've tried to see where's cpanel save `php.ini`

Comment: Can't you contact your hosting provider for that?

Comment: @Ashkar I've go to my hosting provider to live chat with the technical solution, but no answer for now,

Comment: Hi resberry, Where you hosted this?

Comment: @Ashkar I'm hosted using [crockweb](https://www.crocweb.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This could usually appear because of two reasons. If your current PHP version doesn't have the MySQL driver for your script installed or if you have deleted directories from your cPanel account that store information for your MySQL sessions.

If you're certain that the MySQL driver is installed you can contact your hosting provider to make sure that they can restore the basic directories (if deleted)

I had several issues with this on a server and I usually backup the account, terminate it and then restore it from the backup - the default cPanel files are restored.