# How to resolve PHP installation missing error while accessing a website?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to access a website https://worldspills.com from my Chrome browser and I am getting the following error

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

I have checked the existing questions with similar error ([Php - Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694568/php-your-php-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-mysql-extension-which-is-r)). However I don't understand how those solution apply to my context as i am just trying to access a third-person website and not trying to build or maintain my own page.

Is it possible for me to access this website on a simple browser or do i need to get certain applications and addin for that?

Comment: Unless you can access the backend server, there is notthing that you can do using the web browser. Notify the web admin and let them know the problem.

Comment: The probelm is at the other end, you can do nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not the owner of the website you can't do nothing, it's not your browser or your computer problem in general.